Console logging multiple times in React/Next Component
I was trying to make an image gallery and was fetching image objects using redux when this caused some confusion. I thought it must have some kind of downside.
I am aware of the strict mode making it run twice , but the console.log(images) was printing 6 times, I could understand if it was just one or two extra since i am using dispatch which further uses a asyncThunkFunction api call but 6 felt a little too much.
I did thought of logging inside useEffect but it didnot show the updated values
The "Fetching" log is from the async function so it shows its running twice. The empty div is the only thing returning as of now
Any solutions or suggestions for better practices are appreciated
Output

"use client"

import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { fetchImages} from '@/lib/slices/imageSlice';
import { deleteImages } from '@/lib/slices/imageSlice';
import ImagesForm from '@/components/ImagesForm';

function Gallery() {
   const images = useSelector(state =\> state.images.value);
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   console.log(images)

   useEffect(() =\> {
     dispatch(fetchImages());
   }, \[\]);

   return (
     <div className="image-gallery"\>
     </div\>
   );
}

export default Gallery;


Output

I see what looks like an initial mounting render where the images array is empty, and then a couple more renders where the images array is populated. You are console logging as an unintentional side-effect though, so there's no correlation between React rendering the component to compute a diff (cheap and fast) and React flushing the updated UI to the DOM (the expensive part). I don't really see any issue here (other than the unintentional logging side-effect) and it's unclear what you specifically want/need help with.

I see. I thought that the console logging part only occurred when there was a DOM update (which would be expensive occurring multiple times), but if there is no co-relation, then I guess this would be fine.
